# Is there a way for me to make this code even shorter

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop, list-comprehension

My code has the basic aim. Sort a list so that all the odd numbers are to the left and the even numbers are to the right. For example, [1,2,3,4,5] becomes [1,3,5,2,4] However, I kept myself an extra challenge. Make the code as short as possible.

I was able to get it down to this.

```py
l=[int(input("Number: ")) for i in range(int(input("N: ")))]
[l.append((l.pop(l.count(''))) if l[l.count('')]%2==0 else '') for i in range(len(l))]
for i in l: print(f'{i}  ' if i!='' else f'{i}',end='')
```

**Forgetting readability and efficiency**, is there any way to get this down even further, without using exec()?

I thought of adding an else statement to the for loop inside the list comprehension, but apparently, you cannot add for-else statements in list comprehension without Python throwing you a syntax error.

```py
l=[int(input("Number: ")) for i in range(int(input("N: ")))]
[l.append((l.pop(l.count(''))) if l[l.count('')]%2==0 else '') for i in range(len(l)) else for i in l: print(f'{i}  ' if i!='' else f'{i}',end='')]
```

If anyone else has any other ideas, I would love to hear them

**EDIT:** All the answers were using sorted() which I felt was a bit of a cheat. But, after a little more thought, I was able to come up with a new logic that only used two lines, one of which was the input.

```py
l=[int(input("Number: ")) for i in range(int(input("N: ")))]
[print(f'{l[j]}  ' if l[j]%2==i else '',end='') for i in range(1,-1,-1) for j in range(len(l))]
```

If there actually is a way of doing both input, and output in one line, without using sorted() then let me know :)

**EDIT2:** I came up with a way to adapt my 2 line logic into a one line code!

```py
[print(f'{j}  ' if j%2==i else '',end='') for l in [[int(input("Number: ")) for i in range(int(input("N: ")))]] for i in range(1,-1,-1) for j in l]
```

Comment: check out https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` accepts a key function. If we calculate the value of the modulus of 2 and negate the result, we get what we want.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sorted(data, key=lambda i: -(i%2)))
```

The result is `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`.

Comment: "Sorry" to @juanpa.arrivillaga who had the same answer, just some seconds later. Well, great minds think alike. ;)

Comment: I didn't know that there was a function like sorted! Thank you

Comment: If you know of any other way using logic and not a function, that is shorter than the new code I came up with (in my edit of the question), I would love to know about it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
In [1]: l = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [2]: sorted([i for i in l if i%2 == 1]) + sorted([i for i in l if i%2 == 0])
Out[2]: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you! But if you know of any other way using logic and not a function, that is shorter than the new code I came up with (in my edit of the question), I would love to know about it